# Como dar un estilo concreto a un input file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tengo una vista en la que va el profile de un usuario. En ella tiene un input file para cargar la imagen de perfil, pero tiene que quedar como el diseño redondo que os muestro en la foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo único que he conseguido es hacerla de manera cuadrada,  ya que si le doy estilos al div padre y a la imagen y las pongo redondas, la parte del change image se me descuadra y se sale del div.

Os dejo lo que tengo actualmente.

```css
.profile-img {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

.profile-img .file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 70%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
}

.profile-img .file input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-img">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="" />
  <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Change Photo
    <input type="file" name="file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He agregado y comentado el css para que tengas una idea de las ediciones, si planeas cambiar el tamaño del círculo, debes también cambiar los porcentages de la imágen. Espero que te sirva.

```css
.profile-img {
  width: 200px; /* alto y ancho específico para que el círculo sea redondo */
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  overflow: hidden; /* oculta todo el contenido fuera de la caja */
  position: relative;
}

.profile-img img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%; /* Soluciona el problema de ubicación de las imágenes en cajas circulares */
  left: -25%; /* posiciona al centro del contenedor la imagen */
}

.profile-img .file {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 25px;
 
}

.profile-img .file input {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer; /* manita de selección al hacer hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-img">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="" />
  <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Change Photo
    <input type="file" name="file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto es lo que buscaba y las aclaraciones en el css me han ayudado a entender todo.

Answer (score 1):

esto es lo mejor que puedo conseguir en poco tiempo la verdad.
Todo se resume en, que el contenedor, que contiene al resto, debe tener la forma deseada, y lo demás ordenarse dentro de ello. En este caso, `profile-img`.

```css
.profile-img {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.profile-img .file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 100%;

  height: 20%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
}

.profile-img .file input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-img">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="">
  <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Change Photo
    <input type="file" name="file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar un redondeado perfecto, asegúrate de que tu **elemento padre** y la **imagen** sean un cuadrado:

1.- Empecemos a darle estilos a tu elemento padre:

```
.profile-img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

2.- Ahora le daremos estilos a tu imagen:

```
 .profile-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

3.- NOTA la propiedad `object-fit: cover;` hace que la imagen se muestre de manera correcta.

4.- Vamos a darle estilos al elemento que tiene el texto "Cambiar foto":

```
.profile-img .file {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 15px 0;
}
```

Te dejo el ejemplo corriendo para que puedas ver el resultado.

```css
.profile-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.profile-img .file {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 15px 0;
}

.profile-img .file input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-img">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="" />
  <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Change Photo
    <input type="file" name="file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Corrige, el quiere el `change photo` dentro.

Comment: @Excorpion Cierto, acabo de notar bien su diseño.

Comment: Perfecto, es justo lo que buscaba conseguir.